# Limit checkboxes selection per table row

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to limit selected checboxes by 3 per table row, using JS. Each row has an separated checkbox and 5 levels, which can be selected only 2, as in:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="indicator[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="graduations[]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The actual code is as seen on http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/checkboxlimit.shtml:

```js
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
    var checkgroup=checkgroup
    var limit=limit
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length;checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
            if (checkedcount>limit){
                alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
            this.checked=false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could only limit for entire table. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: So, only two should be selected in all checkboxes for graduations?

Comment: Please check spelling in title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to jquery you can use `parent().siblings()` to limit the # of checked checkboxes to 2 per row

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=graduations\\[\\]]').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().siblings().children("input[name=graduations\\[\\]]:checkbox:checked").length >= 2)
            this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2dLu2mu/